# Prosyst Shell Command

Tags: shell, command, osgi

I've implemented console command line shell command in felix.

The interface is

org.apache.felix.shell.Command

Anyone know the analogous interface in Prosyst?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I contacted Prosyst and here is their answer:

The default command interface used by ProSyst is PluggableCommands. You may found further documentation on the API here:

http://dz.prosyst.com/pdoc/mBS_SDK/um/runtime/osgi/docs/framework/api/bundles/com/prosyst/util/pcommands/PluggableCommands.html